# How to Remove whole bookmark from pdf using PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am removing a page from the PDF which has a bookmark link.
After removing the page the bookmark link to this page is no more valid.

I don't find a method from PDFBox api to do this job

Is there any way to remove this bookmark ?
Is there any way to remove total bookmark ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I found how can we remove the whole bookmark

```
PDDocument lPdfWithBookmarks = PDDocument.load(lA4Pdf);
lPdfWithBookmarks.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline(null);
```

I need to find a way to remove a single bookmark which correspondences to removed page